# Selenium can't click on Javascript:Void(0)

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to web scrape a website using Selenium, and there is an anchor element that I need to click that that has an href of: `javascript:void(0)`

If you want to see the website for yourself, I am trying to click on the "I accept" button: http://www.collierappraiser.com/index.html?ref=/main_search/RecordDetail.html&ccpaver=1707221124&dl=yes&sid=901496001&ccpaver=1707221124&FolioID=62428180003

I have tried a couple of things, first: `browser.find_element_by_link_text('I Accept').click()`
I get cannot find element error.

I have also tried finding the element by selector and XPath and it still yields the same error.

I have tried executing js like so: `browser.execute_script("document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].click();")` and it gives me a cannot read property of undefined error.

Please help!

Comment: When you visit the website normally, can you click on the link and go somewhere? Or do you have to do something else first? Hint: what does the "I accept" label refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While inspecting the element observed that there is an iframe embedded on the page which holds your element.

[image]

Required to switch into the frame to access the element inside.

Refer below code:

```
driver.switch_to.frame("rbottom")
driver.find_element_by_id("a_searchlink").click()
```

Comment: I tried to do a little research into frames, but my knowledge of HTML is limited. Could you explain frames like I'm 5?

Comment: refer this https://www.techbeamers.com/switch-between-iframes-selenium-python/